# How do I return/yield a value from a recursive function in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

this seems like a simple thing to do but I just don't seem to find a simple enough answer anywhere for me to grok.

So lets say I have an Elixir function like this:

```
   def fetch_card_ids(offset, total_cards) when offset < total_cards do
       url = "http://some.domanin?offset=#{offset}"
       response = HTTPotion.get url

       #return or yield response here

       fetch_card_ids(offset+24,total_cards)
   end
```

In C# I could yield a return value when iterating something which of course is not the same as recursion but nevertheless: can I do a similar thing in a recursive function in elixir?

Any help would be much appreciated of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If what you want to do is "stream" the response to the caller, then `Stream`s are a good way to go. For example, you could use [`Stream.unfold/2`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Stream.html#unfold/2):

```
def fetch_card_ids(offset, total_cards) do
  Stream.unfold offset, fn
    off when off < total_cards ->
      resp = HTTPotion.get(url)
      {resp, off + 24}
    _ ->
      nil
  end
end
```

This stream will "yield" responses every time it fetches them and stop when `offset` gets greater than `total_cards`.

Comment: I'd say you typo'd at Stream.iterate there. You meant Stream.unfold, no?

Comment: @kaqqao whoops, nice catch! Fixed :)

Answer (score 2):

How about using Streams this way

```
top = div(total_cards,24) +1 # integer division
result = Stream.map( 0..top, fn (offset) -> 
  url = "http://some.domanin?offset=#{24*offset}"
  HTTPotion.get url
  end ) |> Enum.to_list
```

Here `Enum.to_list` simply "yields" the list at the end but you can also process from that list in progressive time using things like `Stream.take` etc